# line and surface integral and (maybe) the chain rule

Tags: calculus, integration

came across this question while studying for my finals. i have no clue on how to approach this one. looking for some clues or some guideness:

there is $\phi(x)\in c^1(\Bbb R)$ and we'll define a surface and a curve:
$$s=\lbrace(x,y,z):z= \phi (\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}), \ x^2 + y^2\le1 \rbrace, \gamma=\lbrace (x,y):y=\phi (x), 0\le x\le1 \rbrace $$

a. prove that $A(s)=2\pi\int _\gamma xdl$ when A(s) is the area of S.
b. find the flux that goes through S towards down by a vector field

Comment: In the statement of the question you have $\phi$ defined with two arguments and later in $s$ and $\gamma$ it only has one argument. I suppose that it's really $\phi(x) \in c^1(\mathbb{R})$. To do part a. I think you'll need to state what the integral for the area of $S$ is and then compare it to the line integral